# In Street Fighter, what does the M stand for in M Bison?

Tags: street-fighter

We keep referring to the leader of the international terrorist group called Shadoloo as M Bison. What really does M stand for?

Comment: All this time I thought it was short for Major- as in the army rank.

Answer (score 34):

Originally, the M. stood for "Mike". The character we know as Balrog was named Mike Bison, and was a Mike Tyson expy (exported character). Fearing a lawsuit, Capcom shuffled the names of Balrog, Vega, and M. Bison. The closest I've found to a canonical reference to [what the M. stands for](https://streetfighter.fandom.com/wiki/M._Bison) is in Street Fighter Alpha 3, where

> He refers to himself by the full title of Master Bison ("Vega-sama" in the Japanese version), with Cammy and the Dolls referring to him in the same way as well.

As a side note, despite a similar name in Japan and the same fighting style and backstory, [Mike](https://streetfighter.fandom.com/wiki/Mike) of *Street Fighter* is a distinct character from Balrog.

Comment: There was a similar issue with E. Honda if I recall.  In the original games, they had a pretty strict character limit on the names, so they had to abbreviate mercilessly.

Answer (score 13):

> Though the "M" originally stood for "Mike" in Japan (for the boxer character), Capcom has never explained what it stands for in Western releases, calling it "part of the character's mystery".
>   
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M._Bison)

His name stands for “Mike Bison”, but is abbreviated for copyright.

Comment: So the M stands for Mystery.